# How to create an Angular 4 project?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I have been asked to create a project in angular 4 while angular 5 is already in market. I have RND for several day to find out how to create an angular 4 project. Meanwhile, I have come to know that downgrading angular CLI will work for me. I did so and created a project which was really an angular 4 project. When I build my project for a production environment, I encounter an error which is listed below.

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 
>   'E:\typescript\lisleware\src'  @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74  @ multi
>   ./src/main.ts

If any kindhearted person can help me in this matter then he/she will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with other node or @angular/cli versions but this worked for me:

Node version: v8.4.0 (I use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm))

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@1.3.2
$ ng new test
$ cd test
$ ng serve
```

Then go to browser and type localhost:4200

If you view your package.json you can find:

```
 .....
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
.....
```

Comment: I have created my angular application using same procedure you have mentioned in your answer above. However, I have used @angular/cli@1.0.0.

Comment: If you found a solution don't forget to post it. It will be helpful to community.

Comment: Sure I will. I am striking my head to find one for last some days.

Comment: I am thankful to you Mr. Jahuuar for your help. It really worked for me. I guess angular/cli version 1.3.2 is a stable one for angular 4.

Comment: Yes, 1.3.2 is the last version of @angular/cli 1.3. I also tried with some of 1.4 but got an error, I think it because node version also. You can view cli versions with "npm view @angular/cli". Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you are really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Install NodeJS & Git Bash

2 - Got to your source-folder, RightClick --> Open Git Bash

3 - Give the Command `$ npm install -g @angular/cli@1.3.2` in your git bash

4 - Give the Command `ng new test` in your git bash
4.1 - Better: `Use ng g -routing test`, a routing module is generated

5 - Move to the New Folder and open Git Bash there

6 - Use `ng serve` in your Git Bash

7 - Open localhost:4200

Here you go, have Fun!

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my question @DoMont. However, I have gone through all these procedures. I am able to create a project and everything, but when I am trying to build the project for the production using `$ ng build --prod` encountering the error which is in the question above.